# Visual C++ Express: fmin and fmax identifier not found?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, identifier

I have compiled this code on Mac so I know there isn't a syntax error, however, in VC++ Express 2010, I get an error saying that fmin and fmax identifier not found. I installed the Windows SDK 7.1 to see if that would fix it and it did nothing :/

```
#include "DigitalDistortion.h"
#include "IPlug_include_in_plug_src.h"
#include "IControl.h"
#include "resource.h"

const int kNumPrograms = 1;

enum EParams
{
  kThreshold = 0,
  kNumParams
};

enum ELayout
{
  kWidth = GUI_WIDTH,
  kHeight = GUI_HEIGHT,

  kThresholdX = 100,
  kThresholdY = 100,
  kKnobFrames = 60
};

DigitalDistortion::DigitalDistortion(IPlugInstanceInfo instanceInfo)
  :     IPLUG_CTOR(kNumParams, kNumPrograms, instanceInfo), mThreshold(1.)
{
  TRACE;

  //arguments are: name, defaultVal, minVal, maxVal, step, label
  GetParam(kThreshold)->InitDouble("Threshold", 100., 0.01, 100.0, 0.01, "%");
  GetParam(kThreshold)->SetShape(2.);

  IGraphics* pGraphics = MakeGraphics(this, kWidth, kHeight);
  pGraphics->AttachPanelBackground(&COLOR_RED);

  IBitmap knob = pGraphics->LoadIBitmap(KNOB_ID, KNOB_FN, kKnobFrames);

  pGraphics->AttachControl(new IKnobMultiControl(this, kThresholdX, kThresholdY,         kThreshold, &knob));

  AttachGraphics(pGraphics);

  //MakePreset("preset 1", ... );
  MakeDefaultPreset((char *) "-", kNumPrograms);
}

DigitalDistortion::~DigitalDistortion() {}

void DigitalDistortion::ProcessDoubleReplacing(
    double** inputs,
    double** outputs,
    int nFrames)
{
  // Mutex is already locked for us.

  int const channelCount = 2;

  for (int i = 0; i < channelCount; i++) {
    double* input = inputs[i];
    double* output = outputs[i];

    for (int s = 0; s < nFrames; ++s, ++input, ++output) {
      if(*input >= 0) {
        // Make sure positive values can't go above the threshold:
        *output = fmin(*input, mThreshold);
      } else {
        // Make sure negative values can't go below the threshold:
        *output = fmax(*input, -mThreshold);
      }
      *output /= mThreshold;
    }
  }
}

void DigitalDistortion::Reset()
{
  TRACE;
  IMutexLock lock(this);
}

void DigitalDistortion::OnParamChange(int paramIdx)
{
  IMutexLock lock(this);

  switch (paramIdx)
  {
    case kThreshold:
      mThreshold = GetParam(kThreshold)->Value() / 100.;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you try to use `fmin` and `fmax` from `cmath` library? Why you don't include the header?

Comment: I did include the header after some quick googling and it still returned the error.

Comment: Because you need to write `std::fmin` / `std::fmax` or use `namespace std`.

Comment: Error: Namespace "std" has no member "fmin". I fixed it though. std::min worked once I included the algorithm header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's C++, you can (and, I dare say, *should*) use `std::min` and `std::max` functions from the `<algorithm>` header.

These are function templates, so they will accept any type for which comparison operators are defined. Just make sure that both arguments are of the same type, else it may fail to compile.

Answer (score 8):

`fmin` and `fmax` are a C99 feature. Visual Studio only implements the C89 standard, so it doesn't have that functions.